# How to solve "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Companion"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, vaadin, vaadin23

I'm following this [guide](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/testing/selenium) to test Vaadin app using Selenium.

The following line:

```java
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

produces the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Companion

In my `pom.xml` I have

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `<version>` tag for **selenium-java** , you will be good to go:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```